# Flutter Mobx changes on an item of ObservableList through @action not updating UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, observable, action, mobx

I have an `ObservableList` of `Category`

This is the declaration line code on `store`

```
  @observable 
  ObservableList<Category> categories = ObservableList<Category>.of([]);
```

And this is the entity code

```
class Category extends Equatable {
  final String categoryName;
  bool isSelected;
  Category({
    required this.categoryName,
    this.isSelected = false,
  });
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        categoryName,
        isSelected,
      ];
}
```

And this is the `@action` code which will update isSelected property on `categories` `ObservableList`

```
  @action
  void changeCategoryIsSelected({required int currentFilterItemIndex, required bool isSelected}) =>
      categories[currentFilterItemIndex].isSelected = isSelected;
```

I don't understand why when calling the `action` the UI is not Updating

Answer (score 2):

change your function be like

```
    @action
      void changeCategoryIsSelected({required int currentFilterItemIndex, required bool isSelected}) 
    {
             categories[currentFilterItemIndex].isSelected = isSelected;
             categories = categories;
    }
```